# django how to get sum of decimal in view?

Tags: python, django

I'm using django to make website.
I want to get total pay by members_pay

one line of views.py

```
members_pay = members.aggregate(Sum('payment_amount')).get('payment_amount__sum',0.00)
```

I tried,

```
total = int(0)
total += total+ memebers_pay
```

But, it occurs error 'unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'NoneType'.
payment_amount is demicalfield, so mayve total is NoneType.

How I get total sum of members_pay ??

Comment: You can inspect which of the two argument is None this way: `print(type(memebers_pay))`, and `print(type(total))`. In order to determine what your problem is you need to find out which of your objects has a value of None. Right now there is not enough information to answer your question so I'm voting to close.

Comment: Thank you! your help is helpful to me:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suspect some of `members` is `None`, change your views:

```
members_pay = members.aggregate(Sum('payment_amount')).get('payment_amount__sum',0.00) if members else 0
```

Comment: It works. Thank you! Does 'if members else 0' mean if members is not None, do the aggregate, else return 0?

Comment: @Julia yes, that's it.